# Does "at all costs" work in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

> I'll get a job this year **at all(any) costs**.

From the dictionary definition of "at all costs" (regardless of the price to be paid or the effort needed), it seems right but I wasn't sure if this fits here.

What I want to say is "I'll find a job this year, no matter how hard it's gonna be. (or no matter what it takes.)"

Or do I need another expression?

Comment: "I'll get a job this year, no matter what the cost." is how I would express it if you want to use "cost".

Answer (score 1):

It depends, what the sentence you're saying **does make sense**. You can see the definition provided by **Dictionary** below;

> 'regardless of the **price** to be paid or the **effort** needed'

However, I would alternate using a **different expression** as it seems too **desperate** or **dramatic**. I'd need some context, but I'd prefer saying something similar but more formal such as;

> "I will find a job for **myself this year**, and I will try everything **effectively** as possible to attain this." *(assuming this is for a CV.)*